# R, dplyr Order groups of entries

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider following exaple data

```
PSE YEAR    ID
1   2014    3
3   2007    1
3   2004    4
3   2002    4
1   2013    3
3   2006    1
2   2016    2
2   2017    2
1   2015    3
3   2003    4
```

> Edit:
>   Wrong one
>   If I use dplyr `arrange(PSE, YEAR,ID)` I get
>
> Corrected one:
>   If I use dplyr `arrange(PSE,ID, YEAR)` I get

```
PSE YEAR    ID
1   2013    3
1   2014    3
1   2015    3
2   2016    2
2   2017    2
3   2006    1 
3   2007    1
3   2002    4
3   2003    4
3   2004    4
```

What I want is

```
PSE YEAR    ID
1   2013    3
1   2014    3
1   2015    3
2   2016    2
2   2017    2
3   2002    4
3   2003    4
3   2004    4
3   2006    1
3   2007    1
```

Probably something easy but somehow I can't get this to be sorted correctly.

Mhhm, somehow this works now but not on my original data. Here is a small sample of the data where the error occurs.

```
structure(list(PSE = c(11280282, 11280282, 11280282, 11280282, 
11630646, 11630646, 11630646, 11630646, 11630646, 11630646, 11630646, 
11630646, 11630646, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 
12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 
12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 
12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 
12106438, 12106438, 12106438, 12335813, 12335813, 12335813, 12335813, 
12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 
12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 
12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 12475347, 
12475347, 12912674, 12912674, 12912674, 12912674), YEAR = c(20152, 
20161, 20162, 20171, 20101, 20102, 20111, 20112, 20121, 20122, 
20131, 20132, 20141, 20042, 20042, 20051, 20051, 20052, 20052, 
20061, 20061, 20062, 20062, 20071, 20071, 20072, 20072, 20081, 
20081, 20082, 20082, 20091, 20092, 20101, 20101, 20101, 20102, 
20102, 20102, 20111, 20111, 20111, 20152, 20171, 20171, 20171, 
20102, 20102, 20111, 20111, 20112, 20112, 20121, 20121, 20122, 
20122, 20131, 20131, 20132, 20132, 20141, 20141, 20142, 20142, 
20162, 20162, 20171, 20171, 20022, 20031, 20032, 20041), ID = c(8171, 
8171, 8171, 8171, 4801, 4801, 4801, 4801, 4801, 4801, 4801, 4801, 
4801, 1646, 1758, 1646, 1758, 1646, 1758, 1646, 1758, 1646, 1758, 
1646, 1758, -1, 3465, -1, 3465, -1, 3465, 3465, 3465, 3465, 4712, 
4770, 3465, 4712, 4770, 3465, 4712, 4770, 8217, 9236, 9237, 9238, 
4947, 4952, 4947, 4952, 5433, 5568, 5433, 5568, 5433, 5568, 5433, 
5568, 5433, 5568, 5433, 5568, 5433, 5568, 6797, 6813, 7123, 7215, 
474, 474, 474, 474)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -72L), .Names = c("PSE", "YEAR", "ID"))
```

PSE 12106438 is problematic.

This is what I get:

```
12106438    20072   -1
12106438    20081   -1
12106438    20082   -1
12106438    20042   1646
12106438    20051   1646
12106438    20052   1646
12106438    20061   1646
12106438    20062   1646
12106438    20071   1646
12106438    20042   1758
12106438    20051   1758
12106438    20052   1758
12106438    20061   1758
12106438    20062   1758
12106438    20071   1758
12106438    20072   3465
12106438    20081   3465
12106438    20082   3465
12106438    20091   3465
12106438    20092   3465
12106438    20101   3465
12106438    20102   3465
12106438    20111   3465
12106438    20101   4712
12106438    20102   4712
12106438    20111   4712
12106438    20101   4770
12106438    20102   4770
12106438    20111   4770
```

What I want is

```
12106438    20042   1646
12106438    20051   1646
12106438    20052   1646
12106438    20061   1646
12106438    20062   1646
12106438    20071   1646
12106438    20042   1758
12106438    20051   1758
12106438    20052   1758
12106438    20061   1758
12106438    20062   1758
12106438    20071   1758
12106438    20072   -1
12106438    20081   -1
12106438    20082   -1
12106438    20072   3465
12106438    20081   3465
12106438    20082   3465
12106438    20091   3465
12106438    20092   3465
12106438    20101   3465
12106438    20102   3465
12106438    20111   3465
12106438    20101   4712
12106438    20102   4712
12106438    20111   4712
12106438    20101   4770
12106438    20102   4770
12106438    20111   4770
```

Comment: what is `class(YEAR)`?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Can you share your sample data via `dput` so we can see what's going on? (Maybe you have some groups, or a factor with a weird level order?) Just put `dput(your_data)` in the console and paste the result into the question.

Comment: `T = arrange(DF, PSE, YEAR,ID)` gives exactly what you want. maybe you're making a typo somewhere

Comment: @AlalehAdn `T` is `TRUE`. Don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Using your sample data and `arrange(DF, PSE, YEAR, ID) %>% filter(PSE == 12106438)` I do not see the same thing you're showing.

Comment: My bad:
arrange(DF, PSE, ID, YEAR) %>% filter(PSE == 12106438)
hopefully this works now!

Comment: Yeah, I don't what your problem is. Your desired output is not sorted in any reasonable way. It's mostly sorted by PSE, then Year, then ID, except you moved the `-1`s out of order so they're together. `arrange(DF, PSE, YEAR, ID)` should do what you want. If it doesn't, please be more clear as to what you want!

Comment: I want each block if IDs to be sorted chronologically. The IDs are not always in an ascending order.